# C linked list or hash table for matrix operations

Tags: linked-list, hashtable

I have matrix in C with size m x n. Size isn't known. I must to have operations on matrix such as : delete first element and find i-th element. (where size woudn't be too big , from 10 to 50 columns of matrix). What is more efficient to use, linked list or hash table? How can I map column of matrix to one element of linked list or hash table depens what I choose to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linked lists don't provide very good random access, so from that perspective, you might not want to look in to using them to represent a matrix, since your lookup time will take a hit for each element you attempt to find.

Hashtables are very good for looking up elements as they can provide near constant time lookup for any given key, assuming the hash function is decent (using well established hashtable implementations would be wise)

Provided with the constraints that you have given though, a hashtable of linked lists might be a suitable solution, though it would still present you with the problem of finding the ith element, as you'd still need to iterate through each linked list to find the element you want. This would give you O(1) lookup for the row, but O(n) for the column, where n is the column count.

Furthermore, this is difficult because you'd have to make sure EVERY list in your hashtable is updated with the appropriate number of nodes as the number of columns grows/shrinks, so you're not buying yourself much in terms of space complexity.

A 2D array is probably best suited for representing a matrix, where you provide some capability of allowing the matrix to grow by efficiently managing memory allocation and copying.

An alternate method would be to look at something like the [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) in lieu of the linked list, which acts like an array in that it's contiguous in memory, but will allow you the flexibility of dynamically growing in size.

Answer (score 0):

if its for work then use hash table, avg runtime would be O(1).
for deletion/get/set given indices at O(1) 2d arr would be optimal.

Comment: Your answer is not  convincing enough. What about size? I wrote that size is dynamically grow and as far as I know linked list are better because size is dynamically by nature. And how can I represent 2d array using linked list / hash table ?

Comment: sorry ,i didnt have time to elaborate.
i saw someone had already answered your question fully ,
be seeing you :)